# Receiving a 404 "Not Found", Using Wildfly, Why?

Tags: url, deployment, wildfly

I deployed a very simple web service in Wildfly yet cannot get a test method to respond.  It seems I have every thing wired up correctly.  When I enter the URL for the test web method, I should receive a response that says "Hello Test".  Instead, I receive a 404.  All I am looking for is information on why I am not getting the expected response.  Any insight would be deeply appreciated.

This URL should be: http://127.0.0.1/pulse-ext-fileAPI/rest/Handler/test.  I derive this URL from three files: the java.js, ConfigApp.java and my Handler.java files.  These are presented below.

I have also included screen prints showing Wildfly is running on my machine, my application is deployed, the "Hello World" from the index.js is displaying, my test method is responding with a 404.

index.js

```html
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

The ConfigApp.java

```
package main.Rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ConfigApp extends Application {
    public ConfigApp(){
    }
}
```

The Handler.java

```
package main.Rest;

@Path("/Handler")
public class Handler {

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces({ "text/plain" })
    public String getHelloWorldJSON() {
        return "Hello Test";
    }
}
```

Here are the screen prints showing that Wildfly is running on my machine, my application is deployed, the index.js is working, the test method is NOT working!

[Wildfly Is Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtJmK.png)

[My Application is Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOm7r.png)

[The Index.js Page is Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYybY.png)

[My Test Method Is Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSXzs.png)

Comment: Try with `@ApplicationPath("/rest")`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the thought.  I tried to no-avail.  I am a bit baffled on this one.  Could it be permissions - I don't think so.  Mistyped path or war file name in some config, I don't think so.  Hmm, gotta be something.

Comment: Which wildfly version are you using? I created a sample project with the same files as yours and it's working(wildfly 14).

Comment: leopal - Thank you VERY much for the effort you put forth.  I am using version 16.0.0, the most recent "final" version.  Perhaps I will try to back off to verion 14 for giggles and see what shakes.  I will let you know what happens.

Comment: So odd, I uninstalled 16 and switched to 14, same error.  leopal - I created an admin user.  What there anything else you had to do with your user to get the app running?

Comment: How are you running wildfly? Through IDE? In my case, I downloaded wildfly14.tar.gz, extract it, placed `war` inside deployments and started server with `standalone-full.xml` profile. Nothing special. Have you checked the logs to verify that everything is started normally?

Comment: So, I am starting Wildfly 16, now, back to 16.0.0 after trying various versions.  I am starting in a terminal window using the standalone server.  When starting Wildfly, the terminal window displays what Wildfly is doing.  In a different terminal window, I enter into the jboss-cli and deploy the war file.  When I do this, I receive two warnings in the terminal window where I started Wildfly.  The warnings are as follows.  I have searched on these warnings and couldn't find anything that really helped...

Comment: 16:20:01,348 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYRS0018: Explicit usage of Jackson annotation in a JAX-RS deployment; the system will disable JSON-B processing for the current deployment. Consider setting the 'resteasy.preferJacksonOverJsonB' property to 'false' to restore JSON-B.
16:20:01,349 WARN  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYRS0015: No Servlet declaration found for JAX-RS application.  In pulse-ext-fileAPI.war either provide a class that extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application or declare a servlet class in web.xml.